# .htaccess 301 redirect including query string, but not file extension

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to create a redirect that will append the original url's query string to the new url.

The old urls look like this: http://example.com/getzip.php?zip=12345
the new urls look like this: http://example.com/zipsearch?zip=12345

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/getzip(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.com/zipsearch%1 [R=302,NC]
```

The code above almost works, but it is also appending the .php extension to the new url, which breaks it. Is there a way to get the query string without the extension?

Answer (score 1):

For your redirect, you need a simple rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^getzip\.php$ /zipsearch [L,R=301,NC]
```

Query string will be automatically carried over to new target URL. Make sure to test in a new browser to avoid old cache.